# Fastest way to strip text of \n, \, \t, \xa0, â\x80\x93 characters in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am converting html data with beautifulsoup, gathering all the text in 'p' tags and converting it to a string. I did this using:

```
source = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

content = ""

for section in source.findAll('p'):
    content += section.get_text()
```

However, when I convert it, tags such as the ones mentioned are scattered throughout the string. I have tried multiple methods to remove all these characters from the strings I am using such as:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', text)`

`content = u" ".join(content.split())`

`text.strip(), text.rstrip()`

Is there a library that can remove these tags from a string. Some of these methods solve some of the problem but most of them still remain.

Edit: Here is an example of a string: https://pastebin.com/2DGECKXa

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your data?

Comment: @PacketLoss here is an example https://pastebin.com/2DGECKXa

Comment: Does `content = content.strip()` not provide the result you're looking for?

Comment: @PacketLoss Not every page I am downloading will be the same format as this. It works for some and not for others. I need something that can universally remove these tags

Comment: @MythKhan, please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to do that using the `.replace` method.

```py
unwanted_chars = ['\n', '\t', 'r', '\xa0', 'â\x80\x93'] # Edit this to include all characters you want to remove

def clean_up_text(text, unwanted_chars=unwanted_chars):
    
    for char in unwanted_chars:
        text = text.replace(char, '')

    return text
```

Then you can apply the function `clean_up_text` to remove all unwanted characters.

```py
new_text = clean_up_text(old_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc

doc = SimplifiedDoc(response.text)
content = ""
for section in doc.ps:
    content += section.text
    # content += section.unescape()
print (content)
```